# Transfer Learning: Labeling Differences

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I was just watching a video on transfer learning (training a model on a larger similar dataset if your dataset is small). I am confused about how the different dataset labels do not interfere with transfer learning.

I understand that transfer learning is typically used if there is only a small amount of data (let's call this `Dataset A`) for your target task (say blurry cat photos) but a large dataset that has similar data (let's call this `Dataset B`, the set of professionally taken and not blurry wolf photos) and whose lower-level feature could be used in learning `Dataset A` (the intuition being that the same edge and curve detection/other lower level features that helps in detecting wolves from `Dataset B` could also help in detecting cats from `Dataset A`). 
From what I understand, you would first train the neural network on `Dataset B`, then set the weights of the last layers to random, and keeping all other parameters constant, retrain on `Dataset A`. 
But given that the label scheme for `Dataset B` would be for wolves, and the labels for `Dataset A` on cats, wouldn't the difference in labeling cause a problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily about machine learning rather than programming. You may consider visiting [Cross Validated](//stats.stackexchange.com) or [Data Science SE](//datascience.stackexchange.com) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is right to some point.
You do not necessarily just set the "weights of the last layers to random" before retraining. But it is more like a cutting of the last layer and replacing it with another newly designed layer.

**Meaning that you could have different types and a different number of outputs for your network, allowing different numbers and types of labels during retraining.**

*Note:*
Tensorflow calls this "simply train a new classification layer on top". More on this and a nice tutorial to grasp the ideas are to be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining).